# pytest: How to suppress traceback for one test case only

Tags: python, pytest

I have the following test case:

```py
    @pytest.mark.parametrize("init_resp", [True, False])
    @pytest.mark.parametrize("mechanism", ["login", "plain"])
    def test_byclient(self, auth_peeker_controller, client, mechanism, init_resp):
        self._ehlo(client)
        client.user = "goodlogin"
        client.password = "goodpasswd"
        auth_meth = getattr(client, "auth_" + mechanism)
        try:
            client.auth(mechanism, auth_meth, initial_response_ok=init_resp)
        except SMTPAuthenticationError:
            if (mechanism, init_resp) == ("login", False):
                client.docmd("*")
                pytest.xfail(reason="smtplib.SMTP.auth_login is buggy (bpo-27820)")
            else:
                raise
        peeker = auth_peeker_controller.handler
        assert isinstance(peeker, PeekerHandler)
        assert peeker.login == b"goodlogin"
        assert peeker.password == b"goodpasswd"
```

As you can see, for one combination of parameters (i.e., `("login", False)`) the test is expected to fail.

Problem is, I still have 2 exceptions messing up the output of pytest:

```
aiosmtpd\tests\test_smtp.py:1054: in test_byclient
    client.auth(mechanism, auth_meth, initial_response_ok=init_resp)
C:\Python\36\lib\smtplib.py:642: in auth
    raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
E   smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (334, b'UGFzc3dvcmQA')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
aiosmtpd\tests\test_smtp.py:1058: in test_byclient
    pytest.xfail(reason="smtplib.SMTP.auth_login is buggy (bpo-27820)")
E   _pytest.outcomes.XFailed: smtplib.SMTP.auth_login is buggy (bpo-27820)
```

(pytest ran using `--tb=short`)

Is it possible to suppress these exceptions *just for this one test case*?

---

### Edit 1

Actually, just after posting this question, I changed the test case to:

```py
    @pytest.mark.parametrize("init_resp", [True, False])
    @pytest.mark.parametrize("mechanism", ["login", "plain"])
    def test_byclient(self, auth_peeker_controller, client, mechanism, init_resp):
        self._ehlo(client)
        client.user = "goodlogin"
        client.password = "goodpasswd"
        auth_meth = getattr(client, "auth_" + mechanism)
        if (mechanism, init_resp) == ("login", False):
            with pytest.raises(SMTPAuthenticationError):
                client.auth(mechanism, auth_meth, initial_response_ok=init_resp)
            client.docmd("*")
            pytest.xfail(reason="smtplib.SMTP.auth_login is buggy (bpo-27820)")
        client.auth(mechanism, auth_meth, initial_response_ok=init_resp)
        peeker = auth_peeker_controller.handler
        assert isinstance(peeker, PeekerHandler)
        assert peeker.login == b"goodlogin"
        assert peeker.password == b"goodpasswd"
```

The result is *a bit* better:

```
aiosmtpd\tests\test_smtp.py:1035: in test_byclient
    pytest.xfail(reason="smtplib.SMTP.auth_login is buggy (bpo-27820)")
E   _pytest.outcomes.XFailed: smtplib.SMTP.auth_login is buggy (bpo-27820)
```

I still want that single 'Exception' to be suppressed, though, if possible.

---

The code snippet above comes from [these lines on GitHub](https://github.com/pepoluan/aiosmtpd/blob/f7c17c310cec8309b6cc4cdfa39fd1163a7a8cd5/aiosmtpd/tests/test_smtp.py#L1054-L1070)

Comment: Refactor it so it's *not* parameterised across entirely different cases. Then you don't need conditional logic in your test either.

Comment: @jonrsharpe it's not "entirely different cases". All cases are similar: I'm checking that interaction between `smtplib.SMTP` and `aiosmtpd` works _according to standards_. In the future, additional AUTH mechanisms will be added (e.g., DIGEST-MD5, CRAM-MD5, etc.) [bpo-27820](https://bugs.python.org/issue27820) bit me, though, so I have to XFAIL that one.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind explicitly writing out every combination of parameters to test, it's very easy to mark one as being expected to fail.  I personally prefer this style, because I just find it to be more clear and more flexible:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    'init_resp,mechanism', [
        pytest.param(True,  'login'),
        pytest.param(False, 'login', marks=pytest.xfail),
        pytest.param(True,  'plain'),
        pytest.param(False, 'plain'),
    ]
)
def test_byclient(self, auth_peeker_controller, client, mechanism, init_resp):
    ...
```

That said, in my hands, the example you gave doesn't output any exceptions.  It just says that 3 tests passed and 1 xfailed.  I suspect that your problem is something to do with how pytest is configured, but it'd be helpful if you could post a minimal working example.

Comment: With a 2x2 matrix, unrolling is workable. In the future, though, I might come upon a similar situation but with, say, a 7x4 matrix. And in that situation, unrolling the matrix to list all 28 combinations is very impractical.

Comment: Also, the XFAIL was not due to pytest configuration, but as the XFAIL message hinted, it's due to [bpo-27820](https://bugs.python.org/issue27820), for which I have submitted [PR 24118](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/24118). If the PR gets merged, I'll "un-xfail" the particular combination.

Comment: For a minimal working example ... that's a bit hard. This is a complex piece of software, the XFAIL happens after a complex SMTP interaction. So rather than trying to "minimize" a "working example", I've given the direct link to my GitHub repo in the edited question instead.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you can append the `xfail` marker outside of the test function. For example, on tests collection finish:

```
import pytest


def pytest_collection_modifyitems(items):
    for item in items:
        if item.name == "test_byclient[login-False]":
            item.add_marker(pytest.mark.xfail(reason="..."))
```

(put that code in a `conftest.py` in your tests rootdir).

Or via an `autouse` fixture:

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def _(request):
    if request.node.name == "test_byclient[login-False]":
        request.node.add_marker(pytest.mark.xfail(reason="..."))
```

This way, the `login-False`-specific code can be removed from the test function alltogether:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("init_resp", [True, False])
@pytest.mark.parametrize("mechanism", ["login", "plain"])
def test_byclient(self, auth_peeker_controller, client, mechanism, init_resp):
    self._ehlo(client)
    client.user = "goodlogin"
    client.password = "goodpasswd"
    auth_meth = getattr(client, "auth_" + mechanism)
    client.auth(mechanism, auth_meth, initial_response_ok=init_resp)
    peeker = auth_peeker_controller.handler
    assert isinstance(peeker, PeekerHandler)
    assert peeker.login == b"goodlogin"
    assert peeker.password == b"goodpasswd"
```

If `client.docmd("*")` is an integral part of the `login-False`-test, then I agree with @jonrsharpe: you have a test function covering two different test cases and you should split it into two separate test cases.

Comment: The `client.docmd("*")` part is not really part of the test, but without that, `smtplib.SMTP` will generate another exception because it somehow got "trapped" inside SMTP AUTH phase. Let's see if I can move the `client.docmd("*")` into the `client` fixture and invoke it only when needed...

Comment: The xfail marker will pass the test but it won't suppress the traceback output.

Answer (score 0):

Your test case should not look like your PROD code where you  `try except` the Exception.
pytest provides a mechanism to expect an exception and then deal with it. Following is the code.

```
with pytest.raises(SMTPAuthenticationError) as exception:
        client.auth(mechanism, auth_meth, initial_response_ok=init_resp)
        .... do something.
```

Comment: Actually did implement that soon after I posted my question. I've edited my question to reflect the current code.